# How to get 'this.parent' element value by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 'td' element in this object how to get parent element value by class name?

```
console.log($this.parent().html())
```

show in console:

```
<td class="nr"><div contenteditable="true">7</div></td><td class="abc"><div contenteditable="true">A</div></td><td class="nazwa"><div contenteditable="true" class="xyz">logic lvl convert</div></td><td class="opis">3.3V to 5V</td><td class="symbol"> </td><td class="ilosc">6</td><td class="nowy">TAK</td><td class="ds"></td>
```

I try to find how to get value from td with specified class but after long time spended on gogle I don't know how to do that :/
I need to get value elements with class #nr, #abc and #ds

Comment: Do you have an event handler setup? Post a [mcve] please. And `$this` should probably be `$(this)`

Comment: what parent do you mean? and as an example please say what is the value of #abc ?

Comment: var $this = $(this)

Comment: @AliSheikhpour value class abc you can see in my question and is "A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to manually get the values of .nr, .abc and .ds..

```js
var trJqObject = $('tr');
$('.clicker.string').click(function() {
  var theValuesAsString; // will be a string
  var separator = ', ';
  theValuesAsString = $('.nr div', trJqObject).text() + separator;
  theValuesAsString += $('.abc div', trJqObject).text() + separator;
  theValuesAsString += $('.ds', trJqObject).text();
  alert(theValuesAsString);
})
$('.clicker.array').click(function() {
  var theValuesAsArray = []; // will be an array
  theValuesAsArray.push($('.nr div', trJqObject).text());
  theValuesAsArray.push($('.abc div', trJqObject).text());
  theValuesAsArray.push($('.ds', trJqObject).text());
  $.each(theValuesAsArray, function() {
    alert(this);
  })
})
```

```css
.clicker {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2px 6px 1px 6px;
  background-color: hsla(188, 100%, 50%, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.clicker:hover {
  background-color: hsla(287, 100%, 72%, 1);
}
.clicker.string {
  left: 0;
}
.clicker.array {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="nr">
      <div contenteditable="true">7</div>
    </td>
    <td class="abc">
      <div contenteditable="true">A</div>
    </td>
    <td class="nazwa">
      <div contenteditable="true" class="xyz">logic lvl convert</div>
    </td>
    <td class="opis">3.3V to 5V</td>
    <td class="symbol"></td>
    <td class="ilosc">6</td>
    <td class="nowy">TAK</td>
    <td class="ds">empty</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="clicker string">click to show values as string</div>
<div class="clicker array">click to loop values array</div>
```

If you reply to this question with more information about what you want to get and what you want to do with it and I'll update this fiddle.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/4uakr7mn/

Comment: I have variable containing whole <tr> from my table and now I want extract from this variable <td> values for specified class name like nr, abc and ds. I need something like `$this.parent().ValueByClassName('#abc')` and it should return `A` and I know that ValueByClassName doesn't exist but looking for something that exist

Comment: @MastaBot If the variable is saved as `var variable = $('tr');` and not as `var variable = $('tr').html();` the above code should work.